# If $n=2$ and $N$ gets large, show that the MLE $\hat{\sigma}^2$ converges in probability but is not consistent

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, asymptotics

Suppose that for $i=1,2, \ldots, N$ and $j=1, \ldots, n$, the r.v.'s $Y_{i j} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\vartheta_i, \sigma^2\right)$ are mutually independent, where the parameters $\{\vartheta_i\}_{i=1}^N$ and $\sigma^2$ are unknown.

Problem 1: If $n=2$ and $N$ gets large, show that the MLE $\hat{\sigma}^2$ converges in probability but is not consistent.

I've shown that $\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{nN}\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^n (Y_{ij} - \hat{\vartheta_i})^2$, and so plugging n = 2 and simplifying I get:

$\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{4N} (Y_{i1} - Y_{i2})^2$.

I was thinking about showing what it converges to in probability, and then if it is not $\sigma^2$, then it is not consistent. But I am a little confused on how to go about showing what it converges to in probability. Could I use LLN and CLT in some way?

Problem 2: Is the MLE $\hat{\sigma}^2$ for $\sigma^2$ consistent if $n=1+[\log (N)]$ and $N \rightarrow \infty$?

I have no clue how to begin with this one because the log term is throwing me off.

Comment: Write $\Delta_i=Y_{i2}-Y_{i1}$. The MLE, as you say, is $\hat\sigma^2=\frac{1}{4N}\Delta_i^2$. This is 1/4 times a mean of iid variables, so you can use the LLN to find its limit and see that it isn't $\sigma^2$.  The same idea works for part 2: work out the mean of $\hat\sigma^2$ and show the variance goes to zero.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.04336.pdf